# How can expand and contract visual selection from a tag block?

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions, custom-text-object

Say I have hierarchical markup like this:

```
<div id="level_1">
  <div id="level_2">
    <div id="level_3">
      watermelon
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can put my cursor on `<div id="level_1">` and hit `%` to jump to the corresponding closing `</div>` tag. I can also visually select inside the block with `vit` or around the block with `vat`.

Say my cursor is on the text "watermelon" and I hit `vat`. I've now selected/highlighted the block starting from `<div id="level_3">` through its ending tag:

```
  <div id="level_1">
    <div id="level_2">
######<div id="level_3">######### highlighted ######
########watermelon############### highlighted ######
######</div>##################### highlighted ######
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I now expand the visual selection / go out one level so that I've now selected around `<div id="level_2">`?

```
  <div id="level_1">
####<div id="level_2">########### highlighted ######
######<div id="level_3">######### highlighted ######
########watermelon############### highlighted ######
######</div>##################### highlighted ######
####</div>####################### highlighted ######
  </div>
```

Once I've done that, how can I come back down a level to where I started?

(HTML is just an example here; answers should apply to any programming language / markup.)

Comment: Well, for HTML: what happens if you keep pressing `at` in visual mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using "a something" text objects (`at`, `a(`, etc.) in visual mode, you can generally keep using them to expand the visual selection. In this case, you should be able to do `vatat` to select the parent element. You could even alternate between `at` and `it` if you want.

`vat`:

[image: vat]

One more `at`:

[image: at]

One last `at`:

[image: at]

But, and it is one of their limitations when used in visual mode, text objects always **grow**. Once you have selected "an" element, the only ways to select an inner element are to:

- start over, by leaving visual mode, re-positioning the cursor, and re-entering visual mode with the correct text object,
- adjust the boundaries of the visual selection with `:help v_o` and various motions.

FWIW, I am convinced that this is more an implementation issue than a conceptual limit.

[You are not the first to ask for that kind of thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937148/vi-increases-the-visual-selection-but-can-i-reduce-the-visual-selection-in-a)