# Can the dot operator expand to the outer brackets if an inner pair was mistakenly highlighted during 'vib' (visualize inner brackets)?

Tags: visual-mode

```
( 2. can dot highlight this too?
   ( 1. 'vib' HERE selects this inner text ))
```

Comment: Well, you can even install Vim on your phone these days so… why don't you try by yourself? But before that, read `:help .` carefully.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/44317/10604

Answer (score 0):

The dot operator is not working in this case but with Vanilla Vim you can just hit `ib` to extend the selection to the outer braces.

Another solution is to add the level of you want to go `v2ib` or if the selection is already set `2ib`.

Remark: it seems that the current version of the [target](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) doesn't support the extension of the the selection with `ib` but does it with `2ib`.